# Radio signals detection circuit

Tags: amplifier, antenna, radio, tuner

What kind of radio signals can I detect with this antenna/tuner circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1f8XO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How can I amplify the incoming signal? I guess I must use a current amplifier but don't understand how to draw the circuit.

Comment: "What kind of radio signals can I detect with this circuit?": None at all.

Comment: ????????? Why? Antenna-Tuner?

Comment: Well, you don't have any way to downconvert the RF signal to an IF or audio frequency, and you don't have an antenna.

Comment: Hmm when the magnetic field of the EM wave hits the wire it will induce a current , how am I nit having an antenna?

Comment: You've not drawn it right, then. If you have an antenna of any sort, you need to explicitly draw it on the schematic, because otherwise all wires in a schematic are assumed to be zero length. That still doesn't help the lack of any downconversion, either.

Comment: Well the wire in any schematic doesn't have 0 length just 0 resistance , it has finite length.

Comment: Okay, I'm not going to pursue this argument any further. Regardless of whether you have an antenna or not, you have no method of downconverting the signal you pick up.

Comment: What is downcovertion? Can you give me a link? I searched it and I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_down_converter but this is for digital signal so it doesn't make sense to be it.

Comment: ahh I see how do we do it? How do we shift the frequency?

Comment: You might receive something from a spark gap transmitter.

Comment: @JellyStrawberry really, you need to start reading a book. **None** of the circuits you've shown so far have anything to do with RF reception or transmission. I don't think any of the answer we'll be giving you here will mean much to you, since you, really, and I don't mean to put you down here, are lacking the most basic ideas, even on how to draw circuits. Sadly, you can't even ask good questions here without doing a schematic.

Comment: I will repeat my comment from your previous question. "A really well designed crystal radio has just enough power for a crystal earpiece. You haven't a hope of driving a loudspeaker without an amplifier." Apart from that you haven't designed a tuner yet.

Answer (score 1):

With those values, you will receive pretty much nothing from RF.

If it were resonant at an audio frequency, then you could (possibly) pick up something from the wires carrying the driving signal to a really high powered loud speaker (say, several thousand watts.)  The real speaker would be so loud, though, that you wouldn't need your "receiver."

The component values you have given won't be resonant at any useful radio frequency.

---

There are inductive transmitters and receivers that work like you seem to want your circuit to work.  The transmitter is simply a big coil driven directly from a powerful audio amplifier.  It dumps a lot of power through the coil.  The receiver is a small speaker (rather, earphone) connected to a really big coil.  The current flowing through the transmitter coil causes a current in the (nearby) receiver coil.  The current in the receiver coil then drives the tiny speaker in the earphone.

Inductive transmitters are only used over very short distances - like, centimeters.  Meters at most.  The received power is a tiny fraction of the transmitted power.

---

What you seem to really want to do is to build an AM receiver (and, given your other questions, possibly an AM transmitter.)

Start by looking at the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_receiver#AM_and_FM) about AM receivers.

Next, look up [crystal radios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio) on Wikipedia.  That page includes this diagram:

[image]

That is the bare minimum for picking up an amplitude modulated radio signal.

It includes an antenna for picking up the signals.  It includes a tuning circuit (L and C1) for tuning to a particular radio frequency.  It includes a diode (D) to recover the audio signal from the modulated radio signal.  It includes a filter (C1) to remove any remains of the radio signal from the audio.  Finally, it includes a **very** sensitive earphone that can produce a (barely) audible sound from the tiny bit of energy that the antenna can pick up.

The Wikipedia page goes into a great deal of detail about how it all works together.

Read it over.  Look up things you don't understand.  If you still can't understand them after looking them up, ask about the parts you don't understand.

---

Just for giggles, I figured up the inductance of an 8 ohm speaker at 1kHz.  That works out to around 1.3 millihenries. That makes your 1µH inductor kind of irrelevant.

It turns out that if you treat a speaker coil as a perfect 1.3 millihenry inductor, then it will be resonant with a 1µF capacitor at about 4kHz.

You could therefore theoretically use your circuit as an inductive receiver for audio.

Answer (score 0):

If your wires can be as long as needed to have an antenna you could detect some really long waves, those which would be hearable if an AC voltage with the same frequency was connected to your speaker. In this case the AC voltage would be harvested by your wires.

1uF capacitor is not especially high reactance at 10kHz, so you could well hear something (=coded data pulses) if there was a naval submarine command radio station nearby. Do not expect to hear anything which is broadcasted by commercial AM or FM radio stations. You must get a signal which is in your hearing range i.e. well below 20kHz, not Megahertzes.

Read this about submarine communication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_with_submarines

I'm sure you should start some studies of electricity and electronics. Im afraid it's best in your case to start from point zero.